# How do i trigger jenkis build for every 2hours through jenkins file

Tags: javascript, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

> Below is my jenkins file:

```js
#!groovy


node('EJ2Release') {
    try {
        deleteDir()

        stage('Import') {
            git url: 'https://gitlab.syncfusion.com/essential-studio/ej2-groovy-scripts.git', branch: 'master', credentialsId: env.JENKINS_CREDENTIAL_ID
            shared = load 'src/shared.groovy'
        }

        stage('Checkout') {
            checkout scm
            shared.getProjectDetails()
            shared.gitlabCommitStatus('running')
        }

        if(shared.checkCommitMessage()) {
            stage('Install'){
                shared.install()
            }

            stage('Build') {
                sh 'npm run build'
            }
        
            stage('Publish') {
                shared.publish()
            }
            if(shared.isProtectedBranch()) {
                stage('SampleBrowser') {
                    shared.triggerSampleBrowserBuild()
                } 
            }
        }

        shared.gitlabCommitStatus('success')
        deleteDir()
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        println(e)        
        shared.gitlabCommitStatus('failed')
        deleteDir()
        error('Build Failed')
    }
}
```

> Below is my groovy script - https://github.com/kumaresan-subramani/jenkins-build/blob/master/groovy

I want to trigger my Jenkins build every 2 hours, i have tried so many option but no luck for me. Can anyone have any suggestion to resolve this.

I have tried like below in jenkins file:

```js
#!groovy


node('EJ2Release') {
    try {
        deleteDir()
        triggers {
          pollSCM 'H/10 * * * *'
        }
        stage('Import') {
            git url: 'https://gitlab.syncfusion.com/essential-studio/ej2-groovy-scripts.git', branch: 'master', credentialsId: env.JENKINS_CREDENTIAL_ID
            shared = load 'src/shared.groovy'
        }
 ----------------etc----------
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `pollSCM`-trigger just triggers your build if there is any commit from your SCM that have to be build.

If you want to trigger every 2 hours also if there is no commit, you have to use the `cron`-trigger:

```
triggers {
    cron('0 */2 * * *')
}
```

Comment: I have already tried this but it throws below error   `[BFA] Scanning build for known causes...
[BFA] No failure causes found
[BFA] Done. 0s
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'triggers' found among steps [ArtifactoryGradleBuild, ArtifactoryMavenBuild, MavenDescriptorStep, acceptGitLabMR, addGitLabMRComment, archive, artifactoryDownload, artifactoryPromoteBuild, artifactoryUpload, bat, bitbucketStatusNotify, build, catchError, checkout, collectEnv, deleteDir, dir, dockerFingerprintFrom, dockerFingerprintRun, dockerPullStep, dockerPushStep,`

Comment: Can you have any idea about this?

Comment: How about the configuration `build periodically` in the job configuration itself outside your scripted pipeline? The error comes from you `scripted pipeline`. It seems like the `triggers` is only allowed in `declarative pipeline`

Comment: thanks but i want to achieve my requiremnt in jenkins file only

Answer (score 2):

Two problems here, the first is as RNoB writes in his answer, you should use cron instead of pollSCM. The second is that you are confusing declarative and scripted pipeline ([see my answer here for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42114067/7509826)).

To set cron trigger in scripted pipeline you should use the properties step (which can be used to set most properties and triggers for a job (see pipeline-syntax generator to see what is available in your installation). So, the following should be sufficient:

```
properties([
    pipelineTriggers([
        cron('H H/2 * * *')
    ])
])

node('EJ2Release') {
    try {
        deleteDir()
        stage('Import') {
            git url: 'https://gitlab.syncfusion.com/essential-studio/ej2-groovy-scripts.git', branch: 'master', credentialsId: env.JENKINS_CREDENTIAL_ID
            shared = load 'src/shared.groovy'
        }
 ----------------etc----------
}
```

Note that I placed the properties step outside of the node allocation, this means that the step is executed as soon as possible after the job starts. And once again, this will only work in scripted pipeline.

Comment: i have tried but build not get triggered, i think issue is -  i have already defined properties in my groovy  script file so that properties in jenkins file not get over-ride.....if this is an issue,any idea to solve this

Comment: I just tried to running the code above (only properties step) on a job where I had manually set a cron trigger. It got overwritten by the cron definition in the pipeline script, so at least for me it works as expected. I suggest you break down the problem, start with a new Job and only parts of the pipeline script. Once that works, run more parts of the script.