# Can Jenkinsfile Stages be refactored for reuse/DRY

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, dry, jenkins-shared-libraries

My jenkinsfile contains stages like these:

```
stages {
  stage('init'){
    steps {
      sh 'do-init'
    }
  }
  stage('region1') {
    stages {
      stage('build') {
        steps{
          script {
            dir("testing"){
              build(region:'region1', labels:"label1")
            }
          }
        }
      }
      stage('delete') {
        steps{
          script {
            dir ("testing"){
              delete('region1')
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  stage('region2') {
    // repeat region1 stage for region2, label2 - edited for brevity
  }
}
```

Is it possible to refactor the inner "region stage" into a shared library, and then just
call it twice in a script {} block?

My attempts so far have ended with the common DSL error "stages not found in steps"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible to achieve what you want, you just need to make sure that in the shared library function you are suing scripted pipeline syntax and not declarative syntax.
For example in your pipeline you can do the following:

```groovy
stages {
  stage('init'){
    steps {
      sh 'do-init'
    }
  }
  stage('region1') {
    steps {
       buildAndDelete('region1', 'label1')
       // or using the Map version:
       // buildAndDelete region: 'region1', labels: 'label1'
    }
   
  stage('region2') {
    steps {
       buildAndDelete('region2', 'label2')
    }
  }
}
```

Now in you shared library `vars` folder you will have a file called `buildAndDelete.groovy`, and its contents will be:

```groovy
def call(Map params) {
    call(params.region, params.labels)
}

def call(String region, String labels) {
   stage('build') {
       dir("testing"){
           build(region: region, labels:labels)
       }
   }
   stage('delete') {
       dir("testing"){
           delete(region)
       }
   }
}
```

You can of course change the input parameters as needed.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this, but got the error that I can't have stages inside script. I'm going to attempt to refactor into another second pipeline and call it from the first.  If that is not satisfactory, I'll attempt a conversion from declarative to scripted, and then refactor into a groovy method.

Comment: @LenJaffe Code above was tested and runs fine - are you trying to run it in a parallel stage or similar?

Comment: I have successfully refactored the pipeline. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem while trying to make a dynamic multiple small stages inside a big stage. You can get the reason why you get the DSL error "stages not found in steps" in the question with id [42113655](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42113655/no-such-dsl-method-stages)

In other way, in my case, I was create a new pipeline with input parameters, so when I want to reuse the same stages, jenkins trigger the second pipeline using [pipeline-build-step plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/) with the important parameters

If you have a long list of regions, combine my solution with a loop in jenkinsfile for dynamic number of regions. You might get the [loop example in here](https://gist.github.com/oifland/ab56226d5f0375103141b5fbd7807398)